# Convert contents of JApplet to java.awt.Image for use with pixelGrabber

Tags: java, japplet

So I am writing a program where the user can draw on the applet window, and when the mouse is clicked, a flood fill algorithm will run and fill the space appropriately. So far, the drawing works, and I know how to do the algorithm, but when I click I cannot get the color of the pixel the mouse is over. At the moment, my code looks like this:
        Point location = e.getPoint();
        handlepixels(this.createImage(getWidth(), getHeight()), location.x, location.y, 1, 1);
I think the problem is in this.createImage(), and I might not know what this actually means. Does it mean the applet? Thanks! Additionally, if there is a better class that pixelGrabber for this any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: I tried to indent the code like the instructions said and it wouldn't work.

Comment: ..well good luck with it.